# How do you track usage of QRcodes?

Tags: qr-code

I don't know if this even is possible, but here goes, how do you track usage of QRcodes? (track scans may be more accurate)

I'm not primarily looking for code snippets (they are of course welcome), but a method for doing this.

Thanks for all your answers :)

Lars

Comment: I don't understand your problem fully? Your would like some way to see how many times a QR-code is scanned? If so it's impossible, but if it's a link you could do a roughly counting on how many visitors you get from a given URL

Comment: You got it right, I thought it was impossible (unless it was an url) but just checked with stackoverflow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the QR codes in question are URLs, put an extra query parameter at the end of the URL containing some means of identifying the QR code. Then, have the target page check for the presence of this query parameter. If the value in the parameter is in your database, increment its counter. You'll obviously have to generate and distribute multiple QR codes with differing values for your query parameter.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I knew it was possible with urls though, but it's always nice when someone answers your questions :)

Answer (score 0):

From my experience the easiest way to track usage of your QR codes is to encode all URLs you are planning to put into QR codes via URL shortener like bit.ly.

By doing so you will achive two results:

1. "free" clicks/scans analytics from bit.ly
2. you have really short URLs which allow you to use smaller QR codes (easier to scan with low-res camera-phones) or better error correction